# leader mapping that includes filename

Tags: vim

Currently I use this:

```
nnoremap <leader>c :ConqueTermSplit ruby
```

which results to:

```
:ConqueTermSplit ruby
```

What I'm trying to do is create a leader key that would result to

```
:ConqueTermSplit ruby ex1.rb<cr>
```

Given the file I'm working with is named ex1.rb

I'm a bit confused on how I'd go about doing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if

> "the file I'm working with"

you meant is the file in your current buffer, you could just create the mapping with `<expr>`:

```
nnoremap <expr> <leader>c ':ConqueTermSplit ruby ' . expand("%p:%h"). "\<cr>"
```

related help doc:

```
:h <expr>
:h expand(
```

the more secured solution would be wrapping the `expand(..)` with `shellescap()` method, in case the path to that file has special chars.

or save the `expand(...)` use the `%` register and `shellescape()`:

```
 nnoremap <expr> <leader>c ':ConqueTermSplit ruby ' . shellescape(@%,1). "\<cr>"
```

Comment: thank you. Your edited solution worked as expected. I'm going to now figure out why it worked :)

Comment: @Ravenous FYI, you can also make it without using `<expr>`, something like: `nnoremap KEY  :exec 'Con... ruby ' . shellescape(@%,1)<cr>` didn't test, but it should work...